# How to read excel data in background using applescript

Tags: excel, applescript

Using following code i am opening and reading the excel data but the file get open in UI.

```
set iRowNo to "A"
set iCellCount to "2"
set SheetName to "Sheet1"
on ExcelFileReadingData(iRowNo, iCellCount, SheetName)
    set xlsFilePath to (path to desktop as Unicode text) & "SofTestSmokeAutomationSuite:DataSheet.xlsx" as Unicode text
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application "Microsoft Excel"
            tell worksheet SheetName
                activate
                open xlsFilePath
                delay 2
                set iCellValue to value of range ("" & iRowNo & "" & iCellCount) as text
            end tell
        end tell
        tell application "System Events"
            tell application process "Microsoft Excel"
                click button 3 of window "DataSheet.xlsx"
            end tell
        end tell
        return iCellValue
    end tell
end ExcelFileReadingData
```

I want to open this file in background as well as data should get read in background there should be any UI interface with excel every thing should be happen in background.

Excel Version = 11,
        O.S MAC = 10.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try this but here's how I would write your code.

```
set iRowNo to "A"
set iCellCount to "2"
set SheetName to "Sheet1"

ExcelFileReadingData(iRowNo, iCellCount, SheetName)

on ExcelFileReadingData(iRowNo, iCellCount, SheetName)
    -- open the file
    set xlsFilePath to (path to desktop as text) & "SofTestSmokeAutomationSuite:DataSheet.xlsx"
    tell application "Microsoft Excel" to open file xlsFilePath
    delay 2

    -- hide excel
    tell application "System Events"
        set excel to first process whose name is "Microsoft Excel"
        set visible of excel to false
    end tell

    -- get the value
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        set iCellValue to (value of range (iRowNo & iCellCount) of worksheet SheetName of workbook 1) as text
    end tell

    return iCellValue
end ExcelFileReadingData
```

Comment: Thanks for looking in to it. but i am getting error when running script second time, error is as follow.

Comment: error "Microsoft Excel got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000

Comment: I tested it and I don't get any errors running it multiple times. It works as expected. You'll have to figure out what is happening on your end.

Comment: Hi...sry for the replay. i found the exact cause if we close the excel from "force quit" (task bar) then it is show above error. but solution is working for me thanks for your valuable support. really it removed my big problem thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Please check mark my answer as the answer to your question so others know you have been helped.